# MVC 3 and Abstract Factory Pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, abstract-factory

I want to go straight to my point here, so is it possible to develop a website using MVC3 and Abstract Factory working together?

Please forgive me for asking but MVC3 is new to me and I want to learn it so I chose it for my new website. But the problem is I don't know if it would work well with Abstract Factory Pattern.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.... You can specify custom controller factories mixed with an IoC container to accomplish what you desire... http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/asp-net-mvc-3-agnostic-inversion-of-control/

http://develoq.net/2010/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc/